# ¿Cómo puedo "resetear" este efecto con JQuery una vez se ha usado sobre dicha imagen?

Tags: jquery

Estoy usando este código en JQuery junto a otro código en CSS para dar un efecto de volteado de la imagen. El problema es que una vez que lo hago sobre una de las imágenes en cuestión, tengo que clickar como 2-3 veces sobre dicha imagen hasta que se vuelva a ver el efecto sobre la misma. Es como si se quedase pillado.

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function girar() {

    $(event.target).click(function () {
        $(event.target).toggleClass("rotate");
    });
}
```

**CSS**

```
.rotate {
    transform: rotateY(360deg);
    transition: all 1s;
}
```

Comment: Y si estás esperando que pase el segundo que dura la animación para volver a ejecutar otra ?

Answer (score 0):

Elimina definicion del evento clic dentro del metodo `girar()` para que te funcione al dar el primer click y tambien tiene que eliminar la clase una vez termine la animacion ya que toggleClass eliminara/agregara la clase si existe o no en el elemento, lo que significa que te funcionara un clic si y otro no(salteado):

```js
function girar(event) {

    // agregamos la clase al elemento que se le dio clic
    $(event.target).addClass("rotate");

     // como la animacion dura 1 segundo, eleminamos la clase 0.2 segundos despues que termine
    setTimeout(function(){
      $(event.target).removeClass("rotate"); 
    },1200);
}
```

```css
.rotate {
    transform: rotateY(360deg);
    transition: all 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://auth.gfx.ms/16.000.27578.1/images/microsoft_logo.svg?x=ee5c8d9fb6248c938fd0dc19370e90bd"  onclick="girar(event)" />
```